# Creating oval/circle inside a rectangle

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-canvas

I am trying to create an oval/circle inside a rectangle. I am trying to do this on canvas for a bitmap image. Here is my code:

```
int x = (int) (midpoint.x*xRatio);
int y = (int) (midpoint.y*yRatio);
int radius = (int) (distance/2);
int left =  x - radius;
int right = x + radius;
int top = y - radius;

canvas.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, paint);
```

Now i want to create an oval/circle inside this rectangle. I tried this and been trying for hours cant get it to work:

```
RectF ovalBounds = new RectF();
//ovalBounds.set(x, y,  (right - left)/2, (bottom-top)/2);
ovalBounds.set(x, y-radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
canvas.drawOval(ovalBounds, paint);
```

Can someone please help me figure this out?
Here is visual to help what i am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - I am doing this on eclipse for an android app.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - sorry will add them..

Comment: Where's your canvas.drawOval-call?

Comment: @isnot2bad - added it above. just did not paste that code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the same bounds than you used for drawing the rectangle:

```
RectF rect = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
canvas.drawOval(rect, paint);
```